# Why my object keeps moving when the path is over?

Tags: path

I'm trying to make an image to follow a curve path, but even after the curve has finished the object keeps moving tangent to where the curve had ended. I'm following several tutorials but no one is having this problem by default.

Comment: If you continue the path animation to an evaluation time > 1.00 Blender will continue to "follow" the curve by extrapolating onward along a straight line if the curve is not cyclic or by continuing to repeat the motion if the path is cyclic.  Please add a screenshot of your follow path modifier and explain which of several techniques you've used to animate the motion along the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable the clamp under path animation in curves tab. Your issue will be solved.

[image]

I was searching for solution for the same issue and came across your post. Though I couldn't find any solution online I figured it out by myself later on. So, I came back here to share this with you, thought it'll be helpful to you too.